# How to create an object in C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

```
void MainWindow::on_actionformattedActivity_triggered()
{
    // todo: Button=> file reading

    Activity* act = new Activity("name",0,1,40,20,true,actNum);
    qDebug() << "actNum" <<actNum;
    activities.append(*act) ;

    qDebug()<< "list element";
    foreach (Activity a, activities) {
        //qDebug() << a.actListWidgetItem->text();
        qDebug() << a.actIsVisible;
        qDebug() << a.actID;
    }

    qDebug()<< "list size";
    qDebug()<<activities.size();
    //timeline->AddTimeLineElement(act->ActStartingPoint() , act->ActRect(), penBlack, brushBlue);

   // ui->listWidgetActivities->addItem(act->actListWidgetItem);
   actNum++;
}
```

Activity Constructor

```
Activity::Activity(QString name, int err, int war,int startTime,int length, bool isVisible,int numberID)

{
   // QListWidgetItem* actListItemWidget = new QListWidgetItem();
   // actListItemWidget->setText(name + "___" + QString::number(err) + "___" + QString::number(war));


    //QPointF* actStartingPoint = new QPointF((numberID -1) * rectHeight, startTime );

    //QRect* actRect = new QRect (0,0,length,rectHeight);

    bool actIsVisible = isVisible;
    int actID = numberID;
}
```

I want to create an object from the class Activities which contains a bunch of data I need to display. whenever I click the button that call this function the system crashes. I decided to check the content of the
QList activities
the output show the correct actNum and List size but random values...

```
actNum 0

list element
true
0

list size
1

actNum 1

list element
true
0
true
0

list size
2
```

How can I create and access an object from Activity class?

Comment: Your code for creating an `Activity` object looks perfectly correct to me. If you are getting a crash and garbage values it is probably because of a bug that happened before the code you posted. Such is the nature of bugs in C++.

Comment: However this code looks to be incorrect `bool actIsVisible = isVisible; int actID = numberID;` Under the assumption that code is trying to initialise data members in the `Activity` class then it should be `actIsVisible = isVisible; actID = numberID;`

Comment: For initialization of members please use constructor initializer lists instead of assignment: `Activity::Activity(QString name, int err, int war,int startTime,int length, bool isVisible,int numberID) : actIsVisible(isVisible), actID(numberID) { /* Empty body */ }`

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your question or how to create a [mre].